# Insert Multiple records in nodejs in single Query

Tags: node.js

I am inserting dynamic records

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO Test (name, email, n) VALUES ?";
var values = [
    ['test', 'demian@gmail.com', 1],
    ['test', 'john@gmail.com', 2],
    ['mark', 'mark@gmail.com', 3],
    ['pete', 'pete@gmail.com', 4]
];
conn.query(sql, [values], function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    conn.end();
});
```

here is example which is working fine

Now my data is here

```
var arr = category_ids.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

}
```

How to make dynamic array of values in for loop

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need an array of arrays, like what `values` is in the example you provided.

### Your example

```
var arr = category_ids.split(",");
var values = [ arr ];
```

or simply

```
var value = [ category_ids.split(",") ];
```

Comment: How to create an array for that